# SQLite "database disk image is malformed" error in an embedded application

Tags: sqlite, embedded

I am trying to use SQLite in an embedded system created using MPC5748G(PowerPC core) with the following behavior.
The SQLite vfs is created on top of ELM Chan FatFS over a USB MSD.

SQLite open function returns `SQLITE_OK` and the first 4011 insert statements are working without any issues.

However, after the 4011 insert, any commands will fail with `SQLITE_CORRUPTED` and `err_msg = "database disk image is malformed"`.

I have read the information from https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html#how_to_corrupt and tried to use f_sync before read and after write operation but with no success.

When the db is loaded on the PC and `pragma integrity_check` is used, it will return this error:
  **in database main
*On tree page 68 cell 0: invalid page number 27656608
Page 100 is never used***

Any hints on how to find the root cause of this issue?

*EDIT* There is no other task which might access or corrupt the DB file.

**UPDATE:** I simulated the same application in Windows environment, with the same(adapted VFS) and there are a couple of differences in the DB binary.
The pictures below show the differences.

[image]
[image]
[image]

What could cause this?

Comment: Have you tried reading the file on a PC using the official `sqlite3.exe`?  Do you get the same 'malformed image' message?

Comment: I tried using https://sqlitebrowser.org/blog/portableapp-for-3-11-2-release-now-available/ but the message is the same

Comment: And if you only do 4000 inserts (i.e., below your apparent failure point), can you still read the database on the PC without problems?

Comment: Do you can build the same db on a PC, store it on the embedded system and try to read it there. Can you trust your file system? Is the count of inserts until failure always the same, or depends it on the size of the inserted data? Do you have a minimal example to reproduce the behaviour?

Comment: Now your question mentions PetitFatFs _and_ FatFs.  Remove the erroneous information rather than adding "EDIT" notes.  Anyone wishing to know what you edited can look at the edit history.

Comment: @jeb I tried your approach with some different results. I created a DB with 13105 elements in the table and the embedded device was able to insert 216 elements before throwing  ```"disk I/O error"```. My level of confidence on the FS is not very high, I have used my specific port and the FS from [link]https://github.com/xluoly/raw-os_sqlite/blob/master/sqlite/os_raw.c